# authenticated AWS API Gateway via javascript AND credentials provider

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk, aws-api-gateway

My setup consists of an AWS API Gateway with IAM access control and AWS cognito for log in.
I access the API already from an Android app and would now like to build a web app (angular2) to do the same.
On Android, I'm using the AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider to supply the API SDK with the required credential.  (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/how-to-generate-sdk.html)

Unfortunately I cannot figure how / if I can do that with the javascript SDK?

I have no trouble using cognito to log in and get the session ID, access token etc. However, the API SDK requires me to provide accessKey and secretKey.

Here's the relevant code snippet from the generated API SDK:

```
var authType = 'NONE';
if (sigV4ClientConfig.accessKey !== undefined && sigV4ClientConfig.accessKey !== '' && sigV4ClientConfig.secretKey !== undefined && sigV4ClientConfig.secretKey !== '') {
    authType = 'AWS_IAM';
}
```

In other words, I have this part working (from some example code):

```
static authenticate(username:string, password:string, callback:CognitoCallback) {
AWSCognito.config.update({accessKeyId: 'anything', secretAccessKey: 'anything'})

let authenticationData = {
    Username: username,
    Password: password,
};
let authenticationDetails = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.AuthenticationDetails(authenticationData);

let userData = {
    Username: username,
    Pool: CognitoUtil.getUserPool()
};

console.log("Authenticating the user");
let cognitoUser = new AWSCognito.CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.CognitoUser(userData);
console.log(AWS.config);
cognitoUser.authenticateUser(authenticationDetails, {
    onSuccess: function (result) {
    callback.cognitoCallback(null, result);
    },
    onFailure: function (err) {
    callback.cognitoCallback(err.message, null);
    },
});
}
```

and now I'd like to use this:

```
this.apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
    accessKey: "anything",
    secretAccessKey: "anything",
    sessionToken: "nothing",
    region: 'eu-central-1'
```

How do I get accessKey, secretAccessKey and sessionToken out of my AWSCognito? I was unable to find any API for that [so far...](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/CognitoIdentityServiceProvider.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cognito is actually made of 3 different services:

- Cognito Your User Pools - What you've integrated here
- Cognito Sync - For syncing user preference data for users
- Cognito Federated Identity - For federating identities (FB, Google or User Pools) into your account and generating credentials.

What the API Gateway client is expecting is credentials that come from Cognito Federated Identity.

See the [Cognito documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/amazon-cognito-integrating-user-pools-with-identity-pools.html) for integrating your user pool with Cognito Federated Identity.

Answer (score 3):

Thank you Bob, for pointing me in the right direction! I've now figured it out and thus for completeness sake, here's the full solution to my problem:

From the service that creates the apigClient:

```
    return CognitoUtil.getCredentials()
    .then(() => 
          this.apigClient = apigClientFactory.newClient({
          accessKey: AWS.config.credentials.accessKeyId,
          secretKey: AWS.config.credentials.secretAccessKey,
          sessionToken: AWS.config.credentials.sessionToken,
          region: 'eu-central-1'}));
```

The getCredentials() method, which is key to get the required temporary credentials:

```
public static getCredentials():Promise{
return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    CognitoUtil.getIdToken({
    callback() {
    },
    callbackWithParam(idTokenJwt:any) {
        let url = 'cognito-idp.' + CognitoUtil._REGION.toLowerCase() + '.amazonaws.com/' + CognitoUtil._USER_POOL_ID;
        let logins = {};
        logins[url] = idTokenJwt;
        let params = {
        IdentityPoolId: CognitoUtil._IDENTITY_POOL_ID, /* required */
        Logins: logins
        };
        AWS.config.region = CognitoUtil._REGION;
        AWS.config.credentials = new AWS.CognitoIdentityCredentials(params);

        AWS.config.credentials.refresh(result => {
        console.log(AWS.config.credentials);
        resolve();
        });

    }
    });
});
}
```

So the key insight here was, that

1. I authenticate to the user pool (shown in my question)
2. I use that with an identity provider to retrieve temporary credentials (getCredentials)
3. I use the temporary credentials out of AWS.config.credentials to setup the apigClient

I hope this is helpful to someone else as well. Certainly the code that I just posted probably could use some refactoring, so any comments on that are very welcome!